# Is there a way to infer an ontology from an XML data file

Tags: xml, owl, ontology, protege

I'm a newcomer to ontologies and Protégé, so this question is going to sound simplistic. I have a dataset of people in an Excel sheet (with stats such as height, age, name, etc.), and I have the Protégé 5.0 beta installed on my computer.
Would it be possible to import this sheet into Protégé, and then automatically infer relationships/groupings of these people (e.g. age ranges) and create an ontology based on those inferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of this task can be done with existing tools, such as Populous [description here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3471341/) [code here](https://code.google.com/p/owlpopulous/).

But the automatic inference of relationships and groupings is a much more complex topic, and while there are a few tools for carrying out ontology based clustering, they are only applicable to very specific and restricted domains. So the answer to the second part of the question is negative; you will have to create the ontology yourself, very likely - or, if possible, import existing ontologies to simplify the task.